# mouseout kill function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom-events

I have a JavaScript function that gets called via `onmouseover` inside an `<a>` tag. This all seems to work and I had a solution in my mind for stopping it by using `onmouseout` or some equivalent inside the html tag. But I'm not sure if this is bad practice.

Is it possible to write the function to listen for a `mouseout` event without touching the html? Or even better include some code inside my current function to kill itself if the mouse leaves?
My html looks like so:

```
    <a onmouseover="callFunction(id)" ......
```

My js function is:

```
    function callFunction(id){
        //does some amazing stuff inside here
    }
```

So what I'm hoping for is instead of including:

```
    onmouseout="killerFunction()"
```

inside the html tag, I want the function to listen for this event by itself but even better would be for the original function - `callFunction(id)` to be able to listen for this and save writing extra functions.

Comment: _"Is it possible to write the function to listen for a mouseout event without touching the html?"_ Yes, it's possible. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( "#id" )
  .mouseout(function() {
    //on mouseout  to do
  })
  .mouseover(function() {
    //on mouseover  to do
  });
```

The jquery way of doing this..

Answer (score 0):

You can register an event handler outside the HTML:

```
document.getElementById("id").onmouseover = function() {
    ..yada yada
    //register another handler here if need be
}
```

Or

```
document.getElementById("id").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
   ..yada yada
}, false);
```

Comment: I prefer using the addEventListener approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just wondering, would that be a no to the possibility of doing this inside the original function then?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery you can listen to events with the `.on()` function without changing the HTML itself:

```
$('html').on('mouseout', killerFunction);
```

You could also do something similar for your `mouseover` event:

```
$('a').on('mouseover', callFunction);
```